# Getting the result for multiple input values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to get the result for multiple percentage values.

Currently, it's only doing it for a single percentage value, e.g. on my screenshot for the -1,0% value.

The `Sales` row depends on the values from the **Sales Growth rates** row.

The result with the sums just sums up the values from `Sales`.

[image]

Is there a way to do it efficiently, without adding 3 more **Sales Growth rates** rows?

**Edit:**

Sorry I may not have expressed myself correctly.

The first two Sales growth rates have base values pre-defined.

Its values after 2019 are multiplied with $F$69 * -1,00%.

The Sales rows values are all multiplied with the according Sales growth rates values.

Thus I just want the Sales Growth Rates also being multiplied with the other percentages, thus having a sum of sales for each of the 4 percentage values.

One solution for example would be to add 3 more Sales and 3 more Sales growth rates rows, each being multiplied with the 4 percentage values. But that's very inefficient.

**Edit2:**

This is a screenshot of how it can be done statically in an inefficient way as I mentioned in the last part of my first edit:

[image]

My goal is to spare the cells with the **green** rows as shown in my first screenshot.

Comment: *The result with the sums just sums up the values from "Sales"* That's because you are summing up range `E72:Q72` What would be the correct result for each percentage?

Comment: Sorry I may not have express myself correctly. The first two Sales growth rates have base values pre-defined. Its values after 2019 are multiplied with $F$69 * -1,00%. The Sales rows values are all multiplied with the according Sales growth rates values.
Thus I just want the Sales Growth Rates also being multiplied with the other percentages, thus having a sum of sales for each of the 4 percentage values.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm totally confused now about what are you trying to achieve. An example of the desired output may help

Comment: Hi, sorry about that! I've edited my question with a correct output result but with the inefficient solution. Does that clear it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is more a mathematical question than an Excel one.

I used a helper column to calculate the growth rates for each scenario.

The formula is `=1+A5*$C$3` where A5 is `-1%` and C3 is 10% under 2019. Drag it down to work out the growth rates for `-0.5%`, `-1.5%` and `-2%`.

Then you can use either of the following formulas to find out the total sales for each scenario:

```
=SUM($B$2:$C$2,$C$2*(B5+B5^2+B5^3+B5^4+B5^5+B5^6+B5^7+B5^8+B5^9+B5^10+B5^11))
```

or

```
=SUM($B$2:$C$2)+SUMPRODUCT($C$2*POWER(B5,ROW($1:$11)))
```

Drag them down to apply to each scenario.

[image: Solutions]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for your idea, that looks brilliant! I got a question: How do you get to exponent $1:$11 for powering?

Comment: @Coon In the **POWER** function you need to define two syntax being `number` and `power`. In this case `number` is the growth rate, and `power` could be a single value or a range of values. If you know how to use **F9 Key** to debug components of a formula, `ROW($1:$11)` is essentially `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}`. Consequently the **POWER** function will calculate the growth rate 11 times with each number in the range, and the result is also a range of powered growth rates, which can be used in a **SUMPRODUCT** calculation. If you understand **Array Formula** this would make more sense to you.